# MSSQL - How do I join table if the data type of field is different?

Tags: sql-server

I'm joining few tables to display results

```
SELECT a.*, b.type 
    FROM [testing].[PICKDETAIL] a
    left join [testing].[ORDERS] b on a.ORDERKEY = b.ORDERKEY
    left join [testing].[LOC] c on A.LOC = c.LOC
    left join [testing].[CODELKUP] d on c.ZCOORD = d.CODE
    WHERE a.STATUS = 0 
    AND b.[TYPE] = 'RT-B'
```

But c.ZCOORD's data type is INT and d.CODE's data is NVARCHAR.
Is there any way for me to join the table with this two fields?

Comment: Use `CONVERT` or `CAST`, however, if `code` is storing an `int` value, then the better answer is fix your data type. A query with a `CONVERT`/`CAST` in the `ON` clause will be non-SARGable, and this suffer on performance.

Comment: Alternatively, if `code` is storing other values that aren't an `int`, then perhaps `ZCOORD` should be stored as an `nvarchar` instead, or you should have a `PERSISTED` computed column with a `TRY_CONVERT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at that query some more, I just had to post an answer and explain some of the problems with it:

```
SELECT a.*, b.type 
    FROM [testing].[PICKDETAIL] a
    left join [testing].[ORDERS] b on a.ORDERKEY = b.ORDERKEY
    left join [testing].[LOC] c on A.LOC = c.LOC
    left join [testing].[CODELKUP] d on c.ZCOORD = d.CODE
    WHERE a.STATUS = 0 
    AND b.[TYPE] = 'RT-B'
```

OK, where to start. Firstly, one of my biggest pet peeve's, your aliasing. [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). The way you have it is very confusing. "d" is for `CODELKUP` and "c" is for `LOC`? How does that make any sense.

Next, your `LEFT JOIN` to `ORDERS`. You have a `WHERE` clause `AND b.[TYPE] = 'RT-B'`. This implicitly turns your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. This'll likely be bad for performance.

Also, `c` and `d` (what tables were they again?) are never referenced again after the `ON` clauses. They aren't in the `WHERE` or in the `SELECT`; so why are they there? They don't appear to be adding anything to the query.

Now, onto your question at hand, `CODE` is a `nvarchar` and `ZCOORD` is an `int`. If you were do leave it as is, then `CODE` would be implicity converted due an `int`, as per [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This will be a problem if you have any values in `CODE` that can't be converted to an `int`; for example `'1A01'`. It'll also mean that values like `'0101'`, `'101'` and `'00101'` would be treated as the same value (`101`); this may or may not be intended behaviour.

Either way, the implicit conversion will make your query non-SARGable, a `nvarchar` has a very different order structure to an `int`. For example with an `nvarchar` the follow expression would be true: `'9' > '8465537632'`. yes, that's right the "number" nine has a higher value than the "number" 8.4 billion.

The right solution here is to fix your data type, however, I don't know enough about your data to give the "correct" answer; thus I'm going to take the safer option of changing `ZCOORD` to an `nvarchar`, rather than `code` to an `int`.

Firstly, add the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE testing.LOC ADD COLUMN ZCOORDn nvarchar(100); --I don't know the data size, so you'll need to change this.
```

Next, you need to update the new column's value:

```
UPDATE testing.LOC
SET ZCOORDn = ZCOORD;
```

Now, we can drop your old column and add the new one:

```
ALTER TABLE testing.LOC DROP COLUMN ZCOORD;
GO
EXEC sp_rename N'testing.LOC.ZCOORDn',N'ZCOORD',N'COLUMN';
```

Now, you can write your query without concern of implicit conversion:

```
SELECT PD.*, --* is probably a poor choice. Declare your columns
       O.[TYPE] --Be consistance. This was [TYPE] in your WHERE, but it's type here.
FROM [testing].[PICKDETAIL] PD --Changed Alias
     JOIN [testing].[ORDERS] O ON PD.ORDERKEY = O.ORDERKEY --Changed Alias, also now an INNER JOIN
     LEFT JOIN [testing].[LOC] L ON PD.LOC = L.LOC --Changed Alias, is this needed though, it's not in the SELECT, so why is it here?
     LEFT JOIN [testing].[CODELKUP] C on L.ZCOORD = C.CODE --Changed Alias, is this needed though, it's not in the SELECT, so why is it here?
WHERE PD.[STATUS] = 0 
  AND O.[TYPE] = 'RT-B';
```

Note the comments I've put in the query above, there are quite a few.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and advice!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following query

```
SELECT a.*, b.type 
    FROM [testing].[PICKDETAIL] a
    left join [testing].[ORDERS] b on a.ORDERKEY = b.ORDERKEY
    left join [testing].[LOC] c on A.LOC = c.LOC
    left join [testing].[CODELKUP] d on c.ZCOORD = CAST(d.CODE AS INT)
    WHERE a.STATUS = 0 
    AND b.[TYPE] = 'RT-B'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all values of `d.CODE` will hold integers, then you can do an explicit cast. If this is the case, please consider changing the column data type to `int` as it will reduce size and boost performance.

```
SELECT a.*, b.type 
    FROM [testing].[PICKDETAIL] a
    left join [testing].[ORDERS] b on a.ORDERKEY = b.ORDERKEY
    left join [testing].[LOC] c on A.LOC = c.LOC
    left join [testing].[CODELKUP] d on c.ZCOORD = CONVERT(INT, d.CODE)
    WHERE a.STATUS = 0 
    AND b.[TYPE] = 'RT-B'
```

If you are not sure or it might hold non-integer values then your choice would be the other way around, converting `c.ZCOORD` to nvarchar.

```
SELECT a.*, b.type 
    FROM [testing].[PICKDETAIL] a
    left join [testing].[ORDERS] b on a.ORDERKEY = b.ORDERKEY
    left join [testing].[LOC] c on A.LOC = c.LOC
    left join [testing].[CODELKUP] d on CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), c.ZCOORD) = d.CODE
    WHERE a.STATUS = 0 
    AND b.[TYPE] = 'RT-B'
```

Neither of these approaches are good for performance, as you are applying functions (converting data types) to the columns, which will invalidate the use of indexes that might exists on these columns.

If you leave it as it is, the SQL engine will most likely convert the most complex type to the simpler one, in this case it will do an implicit cast from `NVARCHAR` to `INT`, as comparing ints is way faster than nvarchars.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to cast d.Code to int datatype.
use

left join [testing].[CODELKUP] d on c.ZCOORD = cast (d.CODE as int)